# ASP VBScript Server side programming

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, overflow

I am new to the VBScript programming. And just now started programming using ASP. The problem is I have quite 60 options as buttons and have to display the page accordingly. Previously we had 60 functions of same functionality. Now I want to convert it to a single function with select case statement. So I passed different numbers as arguments to the function to get which page to display. But I am getting Overflow when I check the argument value. Is it because type conversion error? I have 2 hierachies. SO am passing 2 digit number like 11. Use 11/10 as first and 11 mod 10 as second level selector
I have some Image and Onclicking the code is the following.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function CallFun(a)
select case int(a/10)
case 1
do something
end select
end Function
</script></head><body><img src="Source.gif" onclick = CallFun(11)></body>
```

Comment: Need some code to have any idea what's wrong with it...

Comment: An HTML page like this (with VBScript) is only going to run on Internet Explorer. Also, try [attaching a debugger](https://www.google.co.il/search?num=100&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=2QZ&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=attach+debugger+to+ASP+classic&oq=attach+debugger+to+ASP+classic&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.23484.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.R9TTM_KujjA) to see what's happening in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function test(param)
    dim lvl1 : lvl1 = param\10
    dim lvl2 : lvl2 = param MOD 10
    Select Case lvl1
        Case 1
            if lvl2 = 1 then 
                'some code
            end if
        Case 2
            ' some code
        Case 3
            ' some code
        Case Else
            ' some code
    End Select
End function

Call test(23)     'for example
```

Comment: param\10 is an integer division, param/10 will give you 2.3 if the input is 23, param\10 will give you 2, which is what you want.